# Contextual editing of Pieces related to other pieces

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I've been looking for a solution of this and the only thing that I've seen this issue [On-page, in-context editing of areas nested in array elements does not save](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/issues/993). I've updated apostrophe but I've seen that it doesn't fix my issue.

In my piece-page where I show the fields result of a join with another piece with apos.area o apos.singleton, and it implies that you can edit the fields but when you reload the page or you go to the modal to see if the content of the second piece has change, you see that it doesn't. But if you change the content of the piece that corresponds to the piece-page, this one does change, of course.

Is there anyway, to show the content of that field but without giving the user the possibility of thinking that it is editable, because actually it doesn't maintain the change when the page is refreshed.

**Edit**

I have this code in mi indix.js

```
module.exports = {
extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
name: 'newsletter',
label: 'Newsletter',
pluralLabel: 'Newsletters',
addFields: [
  Other fields... ,
  {
    name: 'body',
    label: 'Newsletter Text',
    type: 'area',
    options: {
      widgets: {
        'apostrophe-rich-text': {
          toolbar: [ 'Styles', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor', 'Table',
           'BulletedList', 'Blockquote', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', 'Split'],
          styles:[
            { name: 'Title', element: 'h3' },
            { name: 'Meta', element: 'h5' }
          ]
        },
        'apostrophe-images': {}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    name: '_articles',
    label: 'Articles',
    type: 'joinByArray',
    withType: 'article',
  },
 ],
};
```

And int the show.html of newsletters page I have this

```
{{ apos.singleton(article, 'body', 'locked-widget', {
     edit: false
  })
}}
```

Comment: I think where we've landed is that the `edit: false` option needs to propagate better. I'm a little confused here though that you have a full area with multiple widget types, but the template is outputting a singleton of a different type. I'd think the template would be an `apos.area`, leaving the widget type off. I say that because if you're looking to display only a specific widget from the joined piece's area, there are helper methods that may help.

Comment: For example, there's the `apos.areas.richText` helper to get all the rich text out from an area. https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/modules/apostrophe-areas#richtext-within-options-api

Comment: Thank you @alexbea , that work for me! But not that I'm using it, I have another question, how could I do the same for images? I've searched for some apos.areas.images or something like that but I didn't see nothing.

Comment: The images helpers are documented here: https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/modules/apostrophe-images#nunjucks-template-helpers. Then using `apos.attachments.url` on what you get from that can get you the image URL. https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/modules/apostrophe-attachments#url-attachment-options-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alexbea commeted on my question, the best way to make this text non-edittable is

```
{{ apos.areas.richText(article.body) }}
```

as same as for the images, it work for me.

```
apos.attachments.url(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Edits to areas being lost is harder to diagnose without a limited test case, but it's easy enough to put a singleton or (I think) area on the page but make it not editable. That'd look like this:

```
  {{ apos.singleton(data.piece, 'example', 'locked-widget', {
    edit: false
  }) }}
```

**Updated the property name per Stuart's comment.**

Comment: That still show me like Ii could edit the content. I want it to see like when you are not loged in as a user. Like it is static text, but only in this page. Tell me if you don't understand me enough please.

Comment: I think the options object should look like `{ edit: false }`

Comment: Yes, just `{ edit: false }`, not `{ controls: { edit: false } }`. Also, please share a simple test project demonstrating the original issue, it could be a bug we're not aware of yet but I'd need to see it in context.

Comment: @StuartRomanek I've changed the html to the one that is now on the question. But it stills give's the impress that you can edit it. The tool bar of the rich text is not showing, it is possible that when you say it is not editable, doesn't show the toolbar but the lines that the is a widget when it's hover, has to been show?